Can I get help with writing my book here?
I have been writing a book for some time now. I've never done this before. Can I get help here? If so, can I post samples of my work to get feedback?

If I were having trouble phrasing something coul dI ask here? Or, how to proceed with an idea?

For phrasing, it depends on how granular the question is. Something broad like How do I keep the gender of my main character purposely ambiguous? is better suited to Writing. Something a lot more specific (eg "what's the word for X?" "what tense for this sentence?") would be better suited to English Language & Usage or ELL (which one depends on your proficiency). The question "how to proceed with an idea?" may or may not be appropriate for Writing. If you have a goal (eg "…w/out being offensive?") and the problem could help others, sure here

If it's something open ended, like "what are some good mythological creatures for a fantasy?" that would only work in chat. (Note: you might find more people in Worldbuilding chat).

Since this is a question about Writing.SE itself, rather than a question about the craft of writing, I've migrated it to Meta.

Not sure why Laurel's first comment was lost in the migration but Amadeus' answer says much of the same thing.

The Reddit writing subreddit wiki lists a couple of websites where you can get feedback on your writing: https://www.reddit.com/r/writing/wiki/critique/ I'd add that there are beta reader groups on Facebook.

No, you cannot post samples of your work to get feedback, that is specifically against the rules for this site.
But yes, you can get help here with the writing process, advice on story construction, rewrite, how to portray different emotions, how to write an action sequence, and so on.
The questions here have to be at least plausibly useful to more than one person; and a review of your work would not be.
I suggest you spend some time reading the questions on this site that do have answers, to get an idea of what kinds of help we can provide.
